# Replace the values of a dataframe with for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

The question is:

1) If there is a data frame with 5 rows as follow:

```
x = c(0,1,3,4,8)
y = c(3,4,6,8,9)
z = c(5,7,3,6,10)
xyz = data.frame(rbind(x,y,z))

x  0  1  3  4  8
y  3  4  6  8  9
z  5  7  3  6 10
```

I want to replace the numbers with 0 if they are smaller than the mean of every row using for loop in R. For example, if `(xyz[i,] < mean(xyz[i,] )` then:

```
x  0  0  0  4  8
y  0  0  6  8  9
z  0  7  0  0 10
```

I use the for loop of R as follow:

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
  j = c(1:5)
  if(xyz[i,j] < rowMeans(xyz[i,]))
     xyz[i,j] = 0
}
```

> Warning messages:
>       1: In if (xyz[i, j] < rowMeans(xyz[i, ])) xyz[i, j] = 0 :
>          the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used……
>       Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a for loop. You can simply do,

```
xyz[xyz < rowMeans(xyz)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you need to loop over j as well as i:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:5) {
    if(xyz[i,j] < rowMeans(xyz[i,]))
    xyz[i,j] = 0
  }
}
```